# Interpolate a date between two other dates to get a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy, interpolation

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
     ISIN             MATURITY       PRICE   
 0  AR121489 Corp     29/09/2019    5.300
 1  AR714081 Corp     29/12/2019    7.500
 2  AT452141 Corp     29/06/2020    2.950
 3  QJ100923 Corp     29/09/2020    6.662
```

My question is if there exists a way to interpolate a date in the column "MATURITY" and get the price value of that date. For example, If I select the date `18/11/2019`, the value of the price on that date should be between `5.300` and `7.500`. I don't know if what I am asking is possible but thank you so much for taking your time to read it and trying to help me.

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) for `interpolate`? "‘time’: interpolation works on daily and higher resolution data to interpolate given length of interval"

Comment: There are many ways to perform interpolation (mathematically). Did you mean "linear interpolation" ?

Comment: @Aimery yes, I want to get the value of the price between two dates by giving another date

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do if you wanted a daily frequency interpolated is first create a daily frequency range with your start and end-dates.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df["MATURITY"] = pd.date_range(start='29/09/2019', end='29/09/2020')
new_df = pd.concat([new_df,old_df], join="outer", axis=1)
new_df["PRICE"] = new_df["PRICE"].interpolate(method = "linear")
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting this error: ValueError: You are trying to merge on datetime64[ns] and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: which line specifically

Comment: Sorry I should say the line of the error. Is the third line

Comment: ah fair enough I just did this in my head I don't have python open. So there are two things you can do, either make the dates your index, and then remove index after, or you can try to implement concat, hang on I will update my answer

Comment: Try my new cocnat version

Comment: Since the price values are not linear, some machine learning algorithms should be used or a better interpolation method.

Comment: Seems like an overkill to create daily-sampled observations when an ask is to just interpolate for a particular date...

Answer (score 2):

I would treat the dates as datetime objects and for interpolation convert the date from datetime object to some time-interval value i.e. either seconds since 20XX-XX-XX 00:00:00 or days and the same I would do for the output timemoments. After that the interpolation works also with `NumPy` interpolate method.

In `matplotlib.dates` there is a method `date2num` and also `num2date` worth to try.